# Android TranslateAnimation not smooth when a videoview is in the same layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-videoview

I have an imageview on which i need to perform a Translate animation.
In the same RelativeLayout, I have a videoview playing a video from local storage.
The animation is not smooth when the video is playing but works perfectly when I remove the videoview from the layout.

What could be the problem?

I tried to change layer type (software, hardware, none)

I monitored my application with gpu profiler and it's performing well,
i reduced overdraw to 1x or 2x

In the below image, i have 2 sliders (imageview 1 and imageview 2) and the video is playing in the middle

Check the translate animation ( it's not smooth) the previous image is still showing in the upper corner while it should be gone within 500 ms)
[image: Here is an example as shown on device]

Comment: use `TextureView` instead of `VideoView`

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: just read `android.view.TextureView` documentation, 3rd paragraph of `Class Overview` section

Comment: thank you, i will give it a try

Comment: The result of using a textureview was that the animation is better but now the video is flickering

Comment: without your code i have no idea what you mean by "flickering", `TextureView` is an enhanced version of `SurfaceView` so most likely it should work better

Comment: flickering= not smooth or hanging

Comment: the code is not simple to be referenced here
I have a class for each type of media (class for video, class for image slideshow which inherit the class View...)
inside video i set the path and play, 
inside image slideshow i decode bitmaps and perform animations